# Change the background color (html format) if a number is less than a threshold

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl, html

I have the folowing file which is called test.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<meta name="generator" content="SQL*Plus 12.2.0">
<style type='text/css'> body {font:10pt Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:black; background:White;} p {font:10pt Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:black; background:White;} table,tr,td {font:10pt Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:Black; background:#f7f7e7; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;} th {font:bold 10pt Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:#336699; background:#cccc99; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;} h1 {font:16pt Arial,Helvetica,Geneva,sans-serif; color:#336699; background-color:White; border-bottom:1px solid #cccc99; margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;-
} h2 {font:bold 10pt Arial,Helvetica,Geneva,sans-serif; color:#336699; background-color:White; margin-top:4pt; margin-bottom:0pt;} a {font:9pt Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:#663300; background:#ffffff; margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; vertical-align:top;}</style><title>SQL*Plus Report</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<table border='1' width='90%' align='center' summary='Script output'>
<tr>
<th scope="col">
NAME
</th>
<th scope="col">
FREE_PERCENT
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
DG_BACKUP
</td>
<td>
50%
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
DG_DATA
</td>
<td>
96%
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
DG_INDEX
</td>
<td>
80%
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
DG_ORA
</td>
<td>
19%
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to find the values that are less than 20% and set the background to red:

```
<td bgcolor="red">
```

using sed or any other tool. 
So, for example,

```
<td>
80%
</td>
```

would remain unchanged, but

```
<td>
19%
</td>
```

wound be changed to

```
<td bgcolor="red">
19%
</td>
```

Script I have tried so far.

```
number_of_lines_test=(`grep -n % test.html |sed -e '1d' |awk -F"[:%]" '{if ($2 <= 50) print $1}'`)
for i in `seq 0 $((${#number_of_lines_test[@]} - 1))`
do
sed -i -e "$((${number_of_lines_test[i]} - 1))s/<td>/<td bgcolor=\"red\">/" test.html
done
```

Comment: welcome to U&L, we are not a free scrpting service, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: actually i am new to scripting and i have thought of using sed the problem is after looping over the lines and check the value after using awk to cut the % sympol but how can i edit line before the matching reasults

Comment: This would be a better question if you clarified what might happen and what won’t.  For example, I’m guessing that, as illustrated, you always have the data on a separate line, and never have `<td>19%</td>` all on one line.  Is the number always the first thing on the line?  Is the number always followed by `%`?  Is the number always followed by `%` *and nothing else*?  Can the number be less than 10?  If so, does it have a leading zero?  (E.g., can we have `7%` or `07%`?  For that matter, how about`007%` or `017%`?)  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Can there be a decimal point (e.g., `17.5%`)?  Can the value be negative?  Will there ever be a line that looks like a value that needs to be colored, but isn’t (e.g., can you have `19%` in the NAME column)?  Is the `<td>` always on a separate line, all by itself?   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you understand that your solution, and [SivaPrasath’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/451737/80216#451819),
run `sed` once *for every data line that needs to be changed*
(in addition to running `grep` and `awk` once, and, in your code, an extra `sed`).

- `awk` and `sed` are very powerful commands. 
  You hardly ever to use them together, or together with `grep`.
- `awk` knows about line numbers. 
  If you find yourself using `grep -n` to generate line numbers,
  and then processing them with `awk`,
  you’re probably making more work for yourself than you need to.
- Running commands takes time. 
  If your file is 100 lines long,
  you probably won’t notice the amount of time SivaPrasath’s answer takes. 
  If your file is a million lines long,
  SivaPrasath’s answer will run `sed` approximately 125,000 times. 
  That will probably be noticeable, and is unnecessary.

If the “value” will always be of the form `NN%`,
where *`NN`* is a two-digit decimal integer between `00` and `19`,
you can do everything with this one `sed` command:

```
sed '/<td>/ { N; s/\(<td\)\(>\n[01][0-9]%\)/\1 bgcolor="red"\2/; }' test.html
```

When it sees a line that contains `<td>`,
it executes the commands in the `{`…`}` braces. 
`N` reads the next line from the file (the one that contains the value)
and appends it to the pattern space. 
Then it does an `s` (substitute) that replaces `<td>` with `<td bgcolor="red">`
if the (percentage) value matches `[01][0-9]` (i.e., `00` through `19`).

If the value can be a single digit
(i.e., `0` through `9` rather than `00` through `09`), then use

```
sed '/<td>/ { N; s/\(<td\)\(>\n[0-9]%\)/\1 bgcolor="red"\2/; s/\(<td\)\(>\n[01][0-9]%\)/\1 bgcolor="red"\2/; }'
```

which is the same logic,
but with one `s` command to handle single-digit values
and one to handle double-digit values. 
Or, if you have GNU `sed` (standard on Linux systems), you can do

```
sed -r '/<td>/ { N; s/(<td)(>\n[01]?[0-9]%)/\1 bgcolor="red"\2/; }' test.html
```

which uses the extended regular expression `[01]?[0-9]`
to match *either* a single-digit value or a two-digit value less than 20.

`sed` can handle non-integers (e.g., `17.5%`),
values with more than two digits (with leading zeroes) and negative numbers. 
If you [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/451737/edit) to indicate what forms you need to process,
I’ll update this section.

---

`awk` programs, while a bit more verbose, are much more powerful,
as they can easily remember information from one line to another. 
So the below script recognizes a broad variety of numeric forms:

```
awk -F% '
        last_was_td {
                  if ($1 < 20) print "<td bgcolor=\"red\">"
                  else print "<td>"
                }
                { last_was_td = 0 }
        /<td>/  {
                  last_was_td = 1
                  next
                }
                { print }
        ' test.html
```

Start reading in the middle. 
If a line contains `<td>`,
the program sets the `last_was_td` flag and skips to the next input line. 
Otherwise the flag is cleared and the line is printed. 
Now reading the script from the top: if the previous line was a `<td>`,
and the number (the first field, as split by the `%` field separator) is less than 20,
we print `<td bgcolor="red">`; otherwise we print `<td>`. 
(The value itself gets printed by the general `print` statement at the end.)

---

All of the above answers write the revised file to the standard output. 
As you know, you can modify the file in place with `sed -i`. 
With `awk`, write the output to a temporary file and copy it back over the input file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
number=(`grep -n "^[0-1][0-9]" test.html | awk -F ':' '{a=$1-1;print a}'`)
for i in ${number[@]} 
do
  sed -i "$i s/.*/<td bgcolor=\"red\">/" test.html
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -e 'put S:g/^^ (\< td) \> $$ \n ^^ (<digit>**2) \% $$ /{$1 < 20 ?? "$0 bgcolor=\"red\">\n$1" !! "$0>\n$1"}/ given lines.join("\n");' 

#OR

raku -e 'put S:g[^^ (\< td) \> $$ \n ^^ (<digit>**2) \% $$] = $1 < 20 ?? "$0 bgcolor=\"red\">\n$1" !! "$0>\n$1" given lines.join("\n");'
```

OR

```perl
raku -e 'put S:g/^^ (\< td) \> $$ \n ^^ (<digit>**2) \% $$ /{$1 < 20 ?? "$0 style=\"background-color:#ff0000;\">\n$1" !! "$0>\n$1"}/ given lines.join("\n");'

#OR

raku -e 'put S:g[^^ (\< td) \> $$ \n ^^ (<digit>**2) \% $$] = $1 < 20 ?? "$0 style=\"background-color:#ff0000;\">\n$1" !! "$0>\n$1" given lines.join("\n");'
```

Examples 1 and 2 substitute-in `bgcolor="red"`. Examples 3 and 4 substitute-in `style="background-color:#ff0000;"`, to produce html that works on modern browsers.

Briefly, the examples use use Raku's ***"big-S"*** substitution operator, which (according to the docs), *"leaves the original string intact and returns the resultant string instead of $/ (the match variable)"*.

Raku's ***"big-S"*** operator is used with Raku's ternary operator in all 4 examples above. Raku's ternary operator is spelled:  "'Condition' `??` 'True' `!!` 'False'".

Examples 1 and 3 use the traditional `S/old/new/` format, which in Raku can take a codeblock in the right half. Examples 2 and 4 use the more modern `S[old] = "new"` or `S[old] = [new]` substitution operator format, which (as demonstrated) can take  ternary operators and/or conditional statements (essentially a codeblock without the curly braces).

https://docs.raku.org/syntax/S$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS
https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-operator_ternary
https://raku.org